# spring use library version not in the mvn repository

Tags: spring, maven

I'm trying to use `spring-session-jdbc:2.0.0.RC2` which is not listed in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session-jdbc/1.3.1.RELEASE

spring session github has newer version than mvnrepository.

How can I add the dependency of the new version in the pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain dependencies that aren't on the central mvn repository, you must communicate to your project that you need it to point to an additional repository. In your case, this snippet, added to your pom, should do:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone-repository</id>
            <name></name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

After declaring this, you just add this to your dependencies, and it will be downloaded:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How to find out spring-milestone-repository has the version I want?

Comment: The spring milestone repository is updated by the Spring Team..so everything which is not there can't be used. Furthermore reading the blog might help https://spring.io/blog/category/releases